# Jquery find each dynamically generated select inside div and add class to select if option value is " "

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically generated select fields inside a div called mydiv.
The id and class names  also for each of my select fields are also dynamically generated.

I am trying to add a class called red-border to each of my select elements inside mydiv based on the value.

for example if Not mapped is selected by default its value is " " empty in my first select than class red-border gets added to my first select

Here is my js please help

```
$('[class^="mydiv"]').find('option').each(function() {
    var myvalue= $(this).val();
    if (myvalue===" "){
        $(this).addClass("red-border");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("green-border");
    }
});

<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv">
    <select id="dynamically_generated_select_169" class="someclass169">
        <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
        <option value="1">Saab</option>
        <option value="2">VW</option>
        <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Another select Each select and its options are all dynamically generated -->

    <select id="dynamically_generated_select_170"class="someclass170">
        <option value="1">Saab</option>
        <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
        <option value="2">VW</option>
        <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine if you fix `Var myvalue= $(this).val();` to `var myvalue= $(this).val();` You have spelled var with a V

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No, it doesn't. He also needs to change `.find('option')` to `.find('select')`

Comment: Nope, he already took "select" with `[class^="mydiv"]`. @Toastrackenigma

Comment: @Berkay Huh. My answer breaks if you change it back to `.find('option')`. The `^=` operator selects all elements where the attribute begins with the value, i.e. all elements where the class begins with `mydiv` in this case. So this just serves to select `mydiv`. Inside `mydiv`, he is then trying to check and compare each `option` tag, when instead he should be trying to check and compare each `select` tag.

Comment: Dude, you are drawing border around "select", ,he wants border around "option". See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n4wgwbfb/1/).

Comment: @Berkay You can't draw borders around `<option>`, it is implemented at an OS level - at least you can't on Webkit browsers on Mac http://imgur.com/a/nrniI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can not add option border color

we try your code with option background and border to select on chnage

```js
// this example for each options

$('.mydiv select option').each(function() {
     var myvalue= $(this).val();
     if (myvalue===" "){
        $(this).addClass("red");
     }else{
        $(this).addClass("green");
     }
 });
 
 // this example on change select
 
 $('.mydiv_2 select').on('change',function() {
     var myvalue= $(this).val();
     if (myvalue===" "){
        $(this).removeClass('green-border').addClass("red-border");
     }else{
        $(this).removeClass('red-border').addClass("green-border");
     }
 });
```

```css
.red {
  background: #f00;
}

.green {
  background: #0f0;
}

.red-border {
  border:solid 1px #f00;
}

.green-border {
  border:solid 1px #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Example for each options</h3>

<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv">

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_169" class="someclass169">
    <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
    <option value="1">Saab</option>
    <option value="2">VW</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
  </select>

 <!-- Another select Each select and its options are all dynamically generated -->

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_170"class="someclass170">
    <option value="1">Saab</option>
    <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
    <option value="2">VW</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
  </select>

</div>

<br>

<h3>Example on change</h3>

<div class="mydiv_2" id="mydiv">

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_169" class="someclass169">
    <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
    <option value="1">Saab</option>
    <option value="2">VW</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
  </select>

 <!-- Another select Each select and its options are all dynamically generated -->

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_170"class="someclass170">
    <option value="1">Saab</option>
    <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
    <option value="2">VW</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: _you can not add option class_. Search about it, with jquery we can. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n4wgwbfb/1/).

Comment: @Berkay Sorry i meant border class to add option border

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` with `on` which will check if the value is `Not mapped` than add a class `red-border`. And second was a minor typo in your code `Var` should be `var`:

```js
$('#mydiv select').on('change', function() {
  var myvalue = $(this).val();
  if (myvalue === " ") {
    $(this).removeClass('green-border').addClass("red-border");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('red-border').addClass("green-border");
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mydiv select').trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.green-border {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv">

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_169" class="someclass169">
  <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">VW</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
</select> // Another select Each select and its options are all dynamically generated

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_170" class="someclass170">
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
  <option value="2">VW</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: So if there are empty values at document ready, client should wait user to change the selection to set red border?

Comment: @Berkay - Added the trigger of document ready. Hope this helps.

Comment: In my opinion; doesn't need for this, but anyway it will work now :)

Comment: If you run the code snippet only the green border is working.

Comment: @Jeremy - Was a small missing stuff. Updated. :)

Answer (score -1):

You had two problems with your code:

- You were finding by `option` tags rather than `select` tags - you cannot style `option` tags, and they do not have a specified `.val()`.
- You had `Var` rather than `var` - JS ***is*** case-sensitive

Note that your code will still only run on first load. You will need to put it into an event handler (for an event like `onchange`) if you want it to update dynamically.

```js
$('[class^="mydiv"]').find('select').each(function() {
 var myvalue= $(this).val();
 if (myvalue===" ")
 {
  $(this).addClass("red-border");

 }else 
 {
 $(this).addClass("green-border");
 }
 });
```

```css
.red-border {
  border:solid 1px #f00;
}

.green-border {
  border:solid 1px #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv">

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_169" class="someclass169">
  <option value=" " selected>Not mapped</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">VW</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>

  <select id="dynamically_generated_select_170"class="someclass170">
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value=" ">Not mapped</option>
  <option value="2">VW</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your div has un Id "mydiv" so you should use it for the selecteur of your selects. Then, you are trying to find "option" but you said yo wanted the select input. Just put your selector to the select.

It should look like that :

```
$('#mydiv').find('select').each(function(){
     var myvalue = $(this).Val();
})
```

Try this out.

Comment: This does not solve OPs problem of wanting to apply classes to the select elements based off their value

Comment: But you already made the ifs for the value. so i'm trying to lead you the point where you can use your if based on the value. When you the select items. you can easily checked their value and apply whatever style you want.